# Can you recommend some Python HTTP client library?

Tags: python, httpclient

I want to use Python to capture info from some websites.
I want the HTTP client to meet this conditions:

1. Supports HTTPS
2. Will not use too much memory, should not generate a lot of processes or threads.
3. Has clear documentation and is actively supported

---

I know that `requests`, `tornado`, or the `gevent` -httpclient
can finish my task, but I do not know which is the best? Or is there some other choices?

Or if there is some other choices written in `C`/`c++`.

Answer (score 26):

Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html). It has the most same API of the various libraries.

Comment: I read the info about tornado ,someone say it efficient, how about the efficiency about requests?

Comment: Tornado is efficient if you can profit from asynchronous processing, i.e. if you need many parallel connections. However, *requests* supports asynchronous requests, too: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests - and it fits better since tornado is more a webserver than a http client library.

Comment: Beware that `requests` uses `urllib3` which automatically repeats requests in certain cases. It may be critical to avoid repeating.

Comment: @temoto: It would probably be a good idea to mention in which cases that happens...

Comment: Here you are:
https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L498 almost any `httplib.HTTPException` or `socket.error`, save for socket timeout and SSL certificate problem will lead to retry.

A bit later on line 516 `if not conn: return self.urlopen(...)` Recursion! Isn't it a nice way to do repeating?

Comment: @Djvu `requests` is the most CPU hungry HTTP library out there. On network efficiency, since it's pure Python, you can combine it with green thread solution like `eventlet` to make thousands of concurrent connections. Can't provide any info on memory efficiency, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [`httplib2`](https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).

- simple (and therefore efficient)
- supports everything one needs and Python 3
- not on Github
- few months may pass before next commit (partly because it just works)

Comment: I use httplib2 atm. It supports py3, but lacks support of proxy on py3. Its nice and it just works, but there is a number of issues on official tracker which are stuck on for years.

Answer (score 0):

here's another suggestions:

1. **[GRequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)** allows you to use Requests with Gevent to make asynchronous HTTP Requests easily.
2. **[httplib2](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2)**
3. **[Requests](https://github.com/requests/requests)**
4. **[treq](https://github.com/twisted/treq)**

Answer (score 0):

I find urllib3 is a great option.  It sets up request pooling for you and handles SSL easily.

Also I think requests now uses it under the hood.

http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/