# Test GET and POST calls

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to test POST and GET calls against an NGINX server.

I need to capture the error codes and verify the response. I was able to test the GET requests by hitting localhost:8080 (NGINX is running on docker exposing 8080), but I'm not sure how to test the POST calls.

Can we construct a dummy request and test POST call? NGINX runs with default page.

Comment: take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you recommend some python http client library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530217/can-you-recommend-some-python-http-client-library)

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to make a post request to an endpoint in python

```
  import requests   
  API_ENDPOINT = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"


  data = {param1:value1, 
        param2:value2}

  #sending post request and saving response as response object 
  r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) 

  #extracting response text  
  pastebin_url = r.text 
  print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)
```